# get null values in flutter firestore implementation

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am calling this method to retrieve the user details from firestore database in flutter application, when the page is loaded it is getting me null values, but upon Hot Reload, it do give the values I require, how should I make sure that the values should be retrieved and should be represented on the screen initially only

```
  getUserDetails(String uid) async{
    firestoreInstance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots().listen((result){
      fullName1 = result.data['fullname'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: @DougStevenson , can you please guide for the query I asked, I know from your profile , that you are a expert in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fullName1 = result.data['fullname'] ?? '';
```

just do that, change the value after the double question mark sign to suit your **fullName1** variable type.

Comment: That I already tried, in the logs values retrieved are shown , but not on the screen, how should I make sure the values are always there in the Text widget if they are retrieved

Comment: add setState(() {}); after i guess